# Mechanize how to add to a select list?

Tags: python, mechanize

I just started experimenting with submitting webforms through mechanize. On [this webpage](http://www.matrixscience.com/cgi/search_form.pl?FORMVER=2&SEARCH=MIS) there is a list of items to select from, `MASTER_MODS`. These can be selected in either `MODS` using a butten `add_MODS` or in `IT_MODS` using a button `add_IT_MODS` (see figure at the bottom). In the form it looks like this (code for form at bottom):

```
 <<SNIP>>
<SelectControl(MODS=[*--- none selected ---])>
<IgnoreControl(add_MODS=<None>)>
<SelectControl(MASTER_MODS=[])>
<SelectControl(IT_MODS=[*--- none selected ---])>
<IgnoreControl(remove_IT_MODS=<None>)>
<IgnoreControl(add_IT_MODS=<None>)>
<<SNIP>>
```

So I want to add to `<SelectControl(MODS=[*--- none selected ---])>` and `<SelectControl(IT_MODS=[*--- none selected ---])>`. However, when I try to add an item directly with

```
br.form[ 'MODS'] = ['Acetyl (N-term)']
```

I get `mechanize._form.ItemNotFoundError: insufficient items with name 'Acetyl (N-term)'`

And when I try

```
br.form[ 'add_MODS'] = 'Acetyl (N-term)'
```

I get `ValueError: control 'add_MODS' is ignored, hence read-only`.

How can I add items to `MODS` and `IT_MODS`?

---

**Figure and code**
[image]

Code:

```
from mechanize import Browser, _http
br = Browser()    
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
url = "http://www.matrixscience.com/cgi/search_form.pl?FORMVER=2&SEARCH=MIS"
br.select_form( 'mainSearch' )
br.open(url)
print br.form
```

Comment: I get "fatal error" on your example link.

Comment: @kobejohn I had a trailing ] in it, fixed now.

Comment: I don't have experience with mechanize but I have a bunch of questions. Join me in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42047/mechanize-how-to-add-to-a-select-list)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this? Explanation in the comments.

```
from mechanize import Browser, Item
br = Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent',
                  'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1)'
                  ' Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
url = 'http://www.matrixscience.com'\
      '/cgi/search_form.pl?FORMVER=2&SEARCH=MIS'
br.open(url)
br.select_form('mainSearch')

# get the actual control object instead of its contents
mods = br.find_control('MODS')
# add an item
item = Item(mods, {"contents": "Acetyl (N-term)", "value": "Acetyl (N-term)"})
# select it. if you don't, it doesn't appear in the output
# this is probably why MASTER_MODS appears empty
item.selected = True
print br['MODS']
# outputs: ['Acetyl (N-term)']
```

Assuming this works, I got it from the comments in [the docs](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/forms.html):

> To add items to a list container, instantiate an Item with its control
>   and attributes:
>   Note that you are responsible for getting the attributes correct here,
>   and these are not quite identical to the original HTML, due to
>   defaulting rules and a few special attributes (e.g. Items that represent
>   OPTIONs have a special "contents" key in their .attrs dict).  In future
>   there will be an explicitly supported way of using the parsing logic to
>   add items and controls from HTML strings without knowing these details. 
>   `mechanize.Item(cheeses, {"contents": "mascarpone", "value": "mascarpone"})`

Comment: @NiekdeKlein not sure if you saw this in chat: I believe that list is intended to be single-selection because you use selection to add/remove items from it, not to choose what to submit. Once things are in the mods list, I think that is enough for them to be submitted and you shouldn't have to worry about selecting them. You probably do need to remove that default item though.