# submitting a form using mechanize, [TypeError: ListControl, must set a sequence]

Tags: python, python-2.7, mechanize, autofill

For an instance,

Let us take facebook signup page where I am trying to submit a sign up form :

```
br.set_handle_robots(False) 
br.open('http://www.facebook.com/r.php')
print br.response()
for f in br.forms():
    print f

br.select_form(nr=1) 
br['firstname']='watever' 
br['lastname']='Kafle'
br['reg_passwd__']='abhibandu'
br['reg_email__']='watever@gmail.com'
br['reg_email_confirmation__']='watever@gmail.com'
br['birthday_month']='01'
br['birthday_day']='20'
br['birtday_year']='1990'
br['sex']='2'
br.submit()

print br.response()
```

Q1)I am getting "TypeError: ListControl, must set a sequence" error. Am I doing anything wrong ?

Q2)P.S. Can someone also suggest how to reload/refresh a page everytime after form submission(Like if I want to create multiple fb accounts) ?

Thanks in advance!

Here is the error message I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ninja\Desktop\facebookautofill\test.py", line 15, in <module>
    br['birthday_month']='01'
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize-0.2.5-py2.7.egg\mechanize\_form.py", line 2782, in __setitem__
    control.value = value
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize-0.2.5-py2.7.egg\mechanize\_form.py", line 1977, in __setattr__
    self._set_value(value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize-0.2.5-py2.7.egg\mechanize\_form.py", line 1985, in _set_value
    raise TypeError("ListControl, must set a sequence")
TypeError: ListControl, must set a sequence
```

when I updated month day and year seeing post at [Submitting a form with mechanize (TypeError: ListControl, must set a sequence)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161764/submitting-a-form-with-mechanize-typeerror-listcontrol-must-set-a-sequence?rq=1)

```
br['birthday_month']=['01',]
br['birthday_day']=['20',]
br['birtday_year']=['1990',]
```

I now get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ninja\Desktop\facebookautofill\test.py", line 15, in <module>
    br['birthday_month']=['01',]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize-0.2.5-py2.7.egg\mechanize\_form.py", line 2782, in __setitem__
    control.value = value
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize-0.2.5-py2.7.egg\mechanize\_form.py", line 1977, in __setattr__
    self._set_value(value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize-0.2.5-py2.7.egg\mechanize\_form.py", line 1998, in _set_value
    self._single_set_value(value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize-0.2.5-py2.7.egg\mechanize\_form.py", line 2021, in _single_set_value
    on, off = self._get_items(value[0])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize-0.2.5-py2.7.egg\mechanize\_form.py", line 2006, in _get_items
    "insufficient items with name %r" % name)
ItemNotFoundError: insufficient items with name '01'
```

Comment: If you're getting an error then: yes, you're doing something wrong! Could you provide the full traceback?

Comment: @jonrsharpe here it is!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mechanize how to add to a select list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245089/mechanize-how-to-add-to-a-select-list)